# Show how many people are currently working on the question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers

Feature request:

Have a way for a user (not the OP) to mark a question as "I am currently thinking about how to resolved it". Show the number of users working on the issue. Some kind of an involvement number.

This will indicate for OP and for others if the question is legit and whether it got other people's attention. If the number is low after some time, then it will tell the OP to rephrase the question or to add more details.

There is the "Viewed times" counter, which is mostly useless.

Also have a way for a user to clear this mark, which will be an equivalent of "I give up" or "I am no longer interested".

Comment: I am currently thinking of a way to answer this.

Comment: @HugoDozois, I am sorry, I don't see where I am implying this.

Comment: What happens when someone clicks the checkbox, so everyone else decides they don't need to put in the effort, and then it's never actually answered?

Comment: @Wooble, good point, didn't think about it.

Comment: This is awesome :| I write a suggestion, get -5, someone finds an exact duplicate where it shows +3. Gotta get a life.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences Just happened that everybody who read the post at the moment where against that idea. The dup is +10 / -7.

Answer (score 2):

The only usage I see to this would be to "let go" questions where you can not be the FGITW, because there are many other people working on it.

Why should you not answer if other people are working on the question? There is nothing saying that your solution is not better than theirs. You should answer a question if you think the question is answerable and that you know you can provide a quality solution to it.

Also, about question legitimacy :

> This *[the counter]* will indicate for OP and for others if the **question is legit**

Why would the question not be legit if it has less attention?

Some very good question stay underground because the tags are underground and some very bad question have a lot of attention because it's about popular tags.

Imagine I make a question tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java), there will be tons of people looking at my question.

Not lets say I make another question tag with [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) there will be a lot less people. Is my question less clear? Is my question not as good as the other, is it less clear? No, not necessarily. One tag is popular the other isn't.

Comment: Even the FGITW idea doesn't work - answers posted in the first ten minutes of a question's existence have their order randomized.

Comment: @Undo well then I really don't see how that number would be used. *Note that if you class them by oldest though they won't be randomized.*