# Feature "There are n users working on an answer" notification

Tags: feature-request, answers

Sometimes I come across a question that interests me and I go forward and start writing my answer.

Occasionally I'll be finishing up my answer, and someone else has posted an equally lengthy & accurate answer. If the other persons answer not too far off from my own, I tend to abandon my answer, upvote the other persons answer, and leave a comment on their answer if anything minor was missed.

I would like to have a feature where I can view the active number of people answering the same question before I begin to write my answer. I can favorite the question and check back later once those answers have been provided and then asses if I should spend time adding my own alternate answer or commenting on the existing answers.

---

There is a duplicate here [When answering, could we be informed that "the following people are already answering this question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/when-answering-could-we-be-informed-that-the-following-people-are-already-answ)

This question can be closed, I couldn't find that one. However.

I don't agree with the accepted answer - I don't really care who is answering the question, I just want to know how many others are. I agree with the comments provided below that the algorithm to determine this would take some time to perfect.

How long till a user is considered inactive and no longer answering the question? How many characters need to be entered before an answer is considered "in progress" (obviously, more than the minimum character limit). These things add complexity, but add for a more richer experience and a feature that I would welcome. Implementing it? Not trivial in the least.

Comment: How will it know that other users are working on answer?  There are plenty of times that I start working offsite first in other tools (SQL Server, SQL Fiddle), then formulate my answer onsite.

Comment: *types one character into the answer box and leaves it*

Comment: Oh this is a duplicate! I remember seeing that one.... Brb! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/when-answering-could-we-be-informed-that-the-following-people-are-already-answ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176669/show-how-many-people-are-currently-working-on-the-question

Comment: Don't worry, duplicates are not a bad thing! Sometimes questions are buried reaaally far away!